# Count html table rows using PHP

Tags: php

I need to display the num of the row (tr) using php, but I don't know how to do this because I am using quotes.

```
    $data['formation'] = '
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: auto !important;">
         <thead style="font-weight: bold;">
           <tr>
              <td>N</td>
              <td>Intitulé</td>
              <td>Organisme</td>
              <td>Date</td>
              <td>Durée (en heures)</td>
              <td>Eval. à chaud / à froid</td>
              <td>Dispositif utilisé</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="table-striped">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    **HERE NUM OF THE ROW**
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_intitule" id="form_intitule" readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_organisme" id="form_organisme" readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_date" id="form_date" readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form_duree" id="form_duree" readonly>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>';
}
```

This is my code:

```
foreach($html->find('table') as $table){ 
    // returns all the <tr> tag inside $table $all_trs = $table->find('tr'); 
    $count = count($all_trs); echo $count; 
}
```

Comment: i have tried a foreach but it's not working

Comment: Post the code please, thx

Comment: `foreach($html->find('table') as $table){ 
     // returns all the <tr> tag inside $table
     $all_trs = $table->find('tr');
     $count = count($all_trs);
     echo $count;
}`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$count = substr_count($data['formation'], "<tr>");
echo "Total rows: ".$count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not a good solution but still simple to use. You can use [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

```
echo substr_count($data['formation'], '<tr>'); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a workaround. But it works just as well.

```
print_r(array_count_values(str_word_count($data['formation'], 1)) );
```

What the above code does is count all words in the `$data['formation']` string. Then, it will devide this into groups and put the results in an array.

It will then print the array and you can see how much times `<tr>` occurs.